# Как с помощью VBA в Word узнать содержимое надписи?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Нужно узнать, что находится в надписи, там у меня поля, которые я хочу при помощи макроса обновлять. Можете подсказать, как узнать текст в надписи в VBA в Word ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("имя уникального заголовка")(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: А какой должен быть заголовок?

Comment: @АлексейMotion НУ посмотрите имя контрола надписи в конструкторе-то... кака-нить "Надпись123" будет...